# For looping list over format function

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am looking at using the formatting function to parse a list of urls over a for loop an run multiple commands for each url.

The following code only gives me **one** of the four users. How can I iterate over each user? 
Implementing a **+1** over each url.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

user_list = {'username':'social_media_username', 'username':'social_media_username' , 'username':'social_media_username' , 'username':'social_media_username'}
url_pattern = 'https://hypeauditor.com/report/{username}'

for user in zip(user_list):
    url = url_pattern.format(**user_list)
    r = requests.get(url)
    response = r.content.decode('utf-8')
    each_soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')

    for url in each_soup:
        get__data = each_soup.findAll(class_ = 'kyb-user-info-v2__el kyb-user-info-v2__el--followers')[1].find(class_='kyb-user-info-v2__sub-title').text
        print(get__data)
```

Comment: Sorry about that Bruno, to be exact, the following code runs for only the first user, I lack the syntax knowledge to implement a **+1**  when parsing the urls. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "user_list" is not a list, it's a dict. A dicts keys are uniques, so since you use the same key ("username") for all users, only one value is actually stored in the dict, ie:

```
>>> d = {"username":"foo", "username":"bar", "username":"baaz"}
>>> d
{'username': 'baaz'}
```

Also, applying `zip()` to a dict only selects the dicts keys:

```
>>> list(zip(d))
[('username',)]
```

The solution is to make `user_list` a proper list - either a list of dicts:

```
>>> users = [{"username":"foo"}, {"username":"bar"}, {"username":"baaz"}]
>>> for user in users:
...     print(pattern.format(**user))
```

or more simply (since you have a single value in each dict) a list of username strings:

```
>>> usernames = ["foo", "bar", "baaz"]
>>> for username in usernames:
...     print(pattern.format(username=username))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for leading me in the right direction. It works like a charm

Comment: Move the 'patter' variable outside the loop - it's a constant so no need to recreate and rebind it over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Change `l` to users list and use this to get the follower details. Am assumming followers are in in this class **kyb-user-info-v2__el kyb-user-info-v2__el--followers**.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

l = [{'username':'social_media_username'}, {'username':'social_media_username'} , {'username':'social_media_username' },{'username':'social_media_username'}]
url_patter = 'https://hypeauditor.com/report/{username}'

for user in l:
    url = url_patter.format(**user)
    r = requests.get(url)
    response = r.content.decode('utf-8')
    each_soup =BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
    followers=each_soup.findAll(class_ = 'kyb-user-info-v2__el kyb-user-info-v2__el--followers')
    for follower in followers:
        # Get follower information
        get__data = follower.find(class_='kyb-user-info-v2__sub-title').text
        print(get__data)
```

Comment: Yes, the second for loop gets `followers` but only for the first `username` I am missing the **+1** in `r = requests.get(url)` I don't know how to apply it.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by +1, what I do is loop over all users in my list and for each user, get list of followers. For each follower get their profile details.Also, as Bruno suggests, users should be a list.